# Android Studio - unable to run my app, 'E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path' and 'E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module'

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

How do I go about resolving this issue to try and run my application? Apologies for the trouble - I am new to Android and programming in general. I've tried to clean, rebuild, restart cache, and create new AVD but I'm getting the same error all the time.

In the logcat, the highlighted lines are follows:

```
01-31 13:19:32.103 1831-5131/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher-auBpKLT1ifS5by9wXNahzg==/base.apk
01-31 13:19:34.351 1645-1815/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
01-31 13:19:36.608 1645-1659/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
01-31 13:20:05.009 1645-1665/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
01-31 13:19:32.103 1831-5131/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher-auBpKLT1ifS5by9wXNahzg==/base.apk
01-31 13:19:32.103 1831-5131/com.android.systemui W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher
01-31 13:19:32.137 2337-2993/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
01-31 13:19:32.139 2477-2669/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0004b40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0003ab0)
01-31 13:19:32.334 1645-1655/system_process I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 62479(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 24(1008KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/15MB, paused 3.760ms total 193.234ms
01-31 13:19:32.682 2477-2669/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-31 13:19:33.390 1645-2449/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher/.MainActivity
01-31 13:19:33.390 1645-2449/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 5157:edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher/u0a79 (adj 900): crash
01-31 13:19:33.392 1645-1664/system_process W/zygote: kill(-5157, 9) failed: No such process
01-31 13:19:33.431 1645-3255/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa00067c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x861d9830)
01-31 13:19:33.432 1645-1664/system_process W/zygote: kill(-5157, 9) failed: No such process
01-31 13:19:33.441 1645-3255/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8e9ad680 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x861d9f00
01-31 13:19:33.477 1645-1664/system_process W/zygote: kill(-5157, 9) failed: No such process
01-31 13:19:33.478 1645-1664/system_process I/zygote: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10079 pid 5157 in 86ms
01-31 13:19:33.648 1645-1745/system_process W/AppOps: Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
01-31 13:19:34.351 1645-1815/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
01-31 13:19:36.567 1388-1605/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 1303533 , only wrote 1026000
01-31 13:19:36.608 1645-1659/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
01-31 13:19:36.608 1645-1659/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
01-31 13:19:52.539 1402-1402/? I/qemu-props: start adbd ...
01-31 13:19:53.760 1645-1659/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
01-31 13:19:53.760 1645-1659/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
01-31 13:19:53.811 1645-1659/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
01-31 13:19:53.812 1645-1659/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
01-31 13:20:00.040 1831-2138/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x8eafada0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8f40bd00)
01-31 13:20:05.009 1645-1665/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
01-31 13:20:11.500 2397-3355/com.google.android.dialer I/Dialer: OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr - OmtpEvent:CONFIG_STATUS_SMS_TIME_OUT
01-31 13:20:11.503 2397-2397/com.google.android.dialer I/Dialer: RetryPolicy - discarding deferred status: configuration_state=4
01-31 13:20:11.505 2397-2397/com.google.android.dialer I/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - no more tasks, stopping service if no task are added in 5000 millis
01-31 13:20:11.517 2397-2397/com.google.android.dialer I/Dialer: VvmTaskReceiver - task received
```

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="383dp"
    android:layout_height="510dp"
    android:minHeight="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major"
    android:minWidth="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
    tools:context="edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            tools:text="Text:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            tools:text="KeyPhrase:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/keyphrase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/encryptGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/encrypt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                tools:text="Encrypt" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/decrypt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:text="Decrypt" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/runButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:text="Run" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="162dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            tools:text="Results:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!